# How to convert the position of an array into a single array?

Tags: arrays

What happens is that I have the following position of an array `rows[0] = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]` which stores certain data: what I want to do is to create a new array with the data that has the position 0 of the array rows so that, for example, I have a new `vector = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]`, so that I could do, for example, `console. log(new[0])`; and have as output "1", and likewise with the other data of the new vector. I was thinking about doing it with some for or while loop, but I can't find the way to do it since row is of position 0.

Comment: Can you share some code of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try with destructuring

```
var rows = [];
rows[0] = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
 

const [new] = rows
console.log(new[0]);
```